# WSAAccept return size not changing

Tags: winapi, network-programming, winsock2, windows-networking

I'm having difficulties using WSAAccept function. I'm using this function on Windows Phone platform. MSDN says this function is supported on Windows Phone, but unfortunately this function never returns me the right length of the sockaddr structure pointed to by the addr parameter. Even if i pass ridicolouos value, it's not changed upon returning.

Has anyone any ideas what could be done to fix that and what could be the reason of such behaviour ?

I will greatly appreciate any help.

**EDIT**
This is how the function is used:

```
sockaddr address;
int size = 28; //it is a max size of union in which it is stored address;

c=accept(s,&address,&size); //where s is the socket;
```

but because accept is not supported on Windows Phone platform, i have a wrapper for it:

```
SOCKET accept(
        SOCKET s,
        struct sockaddr *addr,
        int *addrlen
        )
    {
        return c = WSAAccept(s, addr, addrlen, NULL, NULL);
    }
```

Comment: Please show your actual code. Is `WSAAccept()` returning a valid socket? What is the actual value of `addrlen` upon input, and what is it set to when `WSAAccept()` exits?

Comment: On ipnut actual value is 28, but on the return it stays the same. Even if you pass 60, 5 or other values, they don't change upon returning. The sa_family = 2, and in this project on Windows it does change to 16, but on Windows Phone it doesn't

Comment: Actually if i pass a value greater than 128 it changes it to 128.

Comment: Again, please show your actual code.

Comment: I have edited my question and posted some code in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get proper addrlen by calling getpeername function after accept function. For now it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing invalid parameters to `WSAAccept()`.  If the socket family is `AF_INET`, you must pass a pointer to a `sockaddr_in`, not a `sockaddr`.  If the socket family is `AF_INET6`, you must pass a pointer to a `sockaddr_in6`.  In either case, you must pass an `addrlen` value that is the true size of the `sockaddr_...`.

```
sockaddr_in address;
int size = sizeof(address);

c = accept(s, (sockaddr*)&address, &size);
if (c == INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    // failed, call WSAGetLastError() to find out why...
}
```

```
SOCKET accept(
        SOCKET s,
        struct sockaddr *addr,
        int *addrlen
        )
    {
        return WSAAccept(s, addr, addrlen, NULL, NULL);
    }
```

Comment: Thank You for your answer. I've tried this and it still does not correct the addrlen value. But it is worth mentioning that this function runs fine on Windows platform. I don't know if it could be the answer but after WSAAccept I call getpeername function and it corrects the addrlen value to correct one.